# using for-each-group technique in xsl-fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

can I use for-each-group if yes then can someone show me an example. I am trying to generate a pdf using xsl-fo

I am trying to output it using a table. Please show me an example which makes use of grouping technique and adding values. However, the output should be displayed in a table.

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Library>
<Book code="123">
<BookName>XML</BookName>
<Category>Programming</Category>
<Quantity>10</Quantity>
<Price>100</Price>
</Book>
<Book code="345">
<BookName>Photoshop</BookName>
<Category>Design</Category>
<Quantity>50</Quantity>
<Price>200</Price>
</Book>
<Book code="123">
<BookName>XML</BookName>
<Category>Programming</Category>
<Quantity>5</Quantity>
<Price>100</Price>
</Book>
<Book code="345">
<BookName>Photoshop</BookName>
<Category>Design</Category>
<Quantity>10</Quantity>
<Price>200</Price>
</Book>
  <Book code="456">
<BookName>Illustrator</BookName>
<Category>Design</Category>
<Quantity>100</Quantity>
<Price>300</Price>
</Book>    
</Library>
```

**myxsl-fo**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

<xsl:template match="Library">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-landscape" page-height="300mm" page-width="150mm" margin="1in">
                <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-landscape">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:table border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="thick">
                    <fo:table-body font-size="12pt" font-family="times new roman">


                        <fo:table-row border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-color="#000" border-bottom-width="thick">
                            <fo:table-cell padding-top="1mm" padding-bottom="1mm">
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">Category</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding-top="1mm" padding-bottom="1mm">
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">Book Code</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding-top="1mm" padding-bottom="1mm">
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">Quantity</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding-top="1mm" padding-bottom="1mm">
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">Price</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding-top="1mm" padding-bottom="1mm">
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">Total</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                                
                        </fo:table-row>

                        <xsl:for-each select="Book">
                            <xsl:sort select="Category"/>
                            <xsl:sort select="@code"/>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell padding-top="3mm" padding-bottom="3mm">
                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Category"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding-top="3mm" padding-bottom="3mm">
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding-top="3mm" padding-bottom="3mm">
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding-top="3mm" padding-bottom="3mm">
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell padding-top="3mm" padding-bottom="3mm">
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="number(Quantity)*number(Price)"/>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>                                         
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Instead of xsl:for-each if I try to use xsl:for-each-group then it throws an error saying that the xsl:for-each-group cannot be in that location.

**my current output:**

[image]

however the output I want is shown in the image below:
[image]

thanks

Comment: for-each-group is only available in XSLT 2.0. If you are using XSLT 2.0 take a look at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html as that explains all about grouping in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: If you are using XSLT 1.0, you will need to use a technique called Muenchian Grouping. Take a look at http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html for some an explanation on this.

Comment: the details are provided in this question. My requirement is similar to this question. However while generating the output I am not being able to group it. Please refer to this link for the full question. This question is unsolved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297376/xml-to-pdf-by-xsl-fo

Comment: please check the detailed question mentioned above. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you are using XSLT 1.0 then the **xsl:for-each-group** command is not available. In XSLT 1.0, grouping is usually done using a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). It is worth reading it, and understanding it, as it is a very useful technique in XSLT 1.0 once you understand it.

In Muenchian Grouping, you start off by defining a key which will be used to look up the elements in your group. In your case, you are grouping by Category and Code together, and so they key would look like this:

```
<xsl:key name="GroupByCategoryCode" match="Book" use="concat(Category, '|', @code)"/>
```

Now, in XSLT 2.0, you would probably write this...

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Library/Book" group-by="concat(Category, '|', @code)">
```

However, in XSLT 1.0 you have to write this (I've added lots of indentation to improve readability)

```
<xsl:for-each 
     select="Library/Book
             [
               generate-id() = 
               generate-id
               (
                    key('GroupByCategoryCode', concat(Category, '|', @code))[1]
               )
             ]">
```

(Using xsl:apply-templates here would also work).

What this is going is looking at all **Book** elements, and checking its combination of "Category" and "Code" to see whether it is the first occurrence of that element in the key. Effectively it will pick the distinct occurences of "Category" and "Code".

In XSLT 2.0, you would use "current-group" to then iterate over all elements in the group. In XSLT 1.0, you would just use the key

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('GroupByCategoryCode', concat(Category, '|', @code))">
```

Although, in this particular case, you don't need to do a for-each, as you are just summing up Quantity in each group.

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="sum(key('GroupByCategoryCode', concat(Category, '|', @code))/Quantity)"/>
```

Or, to improve readability abit...

```
  <xsl:variable name="currentGroup" select="key('GroupByCategoryCode', concat(Category, '|', @code))"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="sum($currentGroup/Quantity)"/>
```

Try this XSLT. To keep things simple (and because I don't know xsl-fo) I am outputting HTML to demonstrate the principle. All you need to do is to replace the HTML tags with their xsl-fo equivalents

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="GroupByCategoryCode" match="Book" use="concat(Category, '|', @code)"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h1>Books Information</h1>
            <table border="1">
               <tr>
                  <th>Category</th>
                  <th>Book Code</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th>Unit Price</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="Library/Book[generate-id() = generate-id(key('GroupByCategoryCode', concat(Category, '|', @code))[1])]">
                  <xsl:sort select="Category"/>
                  <xsl:sort select="@code"/>
               </xsl:apply-templates>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Book">
      <xsl:variable name="currentGroup" select="key('GroupByCategoryCode', concat(Category, '|', @code))"/>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Category"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($currentGroup/Quantity)"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($currentGroup/Quantity) * Price"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: To show the word 'Repeated' instead of the Category for repeated categories, you could view this as grouping by category, and only show the category name for the first one in the group.

So, add the following key to the XSLT, to allow you to look up books by category

```
<xsl:key name="GroupByCategory" match="Book" use="Category"/>
```

Then, you need to pick the distinct categories (this should surround the existing **xsl:apply-templates**)

```
<xsl:for-each select="Library/Book[generate-id() = generate-id(key('GroupByCategory', Category)[1])]">
```

Then within the template matching **Book** you could then determine whether to show the category name or "defined" like so

```
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
         <xsl:value-of select="Category" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:text>Repeated</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="GroupByCategoryCode" match="Book" use="concat(Category, '|', @code)"/>
   <xsl:key name="GroupByCategory" match="Book" use="Category"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h1>Books Information</h1>
            <table border="1">
               <tr>
                  <th>Category</th>
                  <th>Book Code</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th>Unit Price</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="Library/Book[generate-id() = generate-id(key('GroupByCategory', Category)[1])]">
                  <xsl:sort select="Category"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('GroupByCategory', Category)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('GroupByCategoryCode', concat(Category, '|', @code))[1])]">
                     <xsl:sort select="@code"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Book">
     <xsl:variable name="Category">
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
             <xsl:value-of select="Category" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:text>Repeated</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="currentGroup" select="key('GroupByCategoryCode', concat(Category, '|', @code))"/>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Category"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($currentGroup/Quantity)"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($currentGroup/Quantity) * Price"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks to all. I will try it once and come back to you.

Comment: Hello Tim, Your xslt is perfect and it worked fine. however can you let me know How I can show the word repeated instead of Design if it comes more than once on the table. you can check the snapshots I have attached. thanks again

Comment: Also Tim, Can you show me the grand total in a different row at the end of the table.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to explain how to show the word "Repeated". For the Grand Total you are probably better asking a whole new question for this as it is a bit trickier to do in XSLT 1.0 and so may require a longer answer. As this question was mainly about grouping, it is best to keep it separate to any issue with Totals. Thanks!